# Problems with sharing public key

Tags: android, security, aes, public-key-encryption

I am using a client/server where I have given every client a public key in the application itself and at the start of any conversation between the client and server they share a AES key using this public/private key pair and then every thing is encrypted using this key ....

I wanted to know what problems arise with this model....one would be the server cannot verify who is actually sending the data .digital signature ...but the user would later send it's credentials ....

what can a MIM attack do here?

Answer (score 1):

In, short this is complicated, don't try to reinvent it, just use SSL. There are multiple ways to get this wrong, unless this is for academic purposes, don't do it.

Comment: Yeah i understand SSL would be the best  ...how do i make someone understand the problems with it...

Comment: Get a good network security textbook :) You have to take care of (at least): verifying each party's identity; negotiating a common encryption algorithm; use a different strong symmetric key each time; prevent replays; ensure message integrity. Try to check how your custom scheme does (or doesn't) all this things, and you'll see  where the problems are.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You are taking a risk here. One(attacker) can take this `public key` and act as a trusted `client`. I am guessing you have created `public key` using `ssh-keygen`.

Comment: i have used ..open ssl to create it